# Framework for generating a web client for editing EntityFramework 4 data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, user-interface

Imagine there is an application with EF 4 data storage.

I need to develop a web client, which would allow to perform CRUD operations on these data with minimum effort.

Is there a framework or a tool, which would allow to quickly generate UI for these actions from existing data schema (similar to [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo), for example) ?

Comment: In the MS world, look for "Dynamic Data". And/or LightSwitch.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks. Please submit your comment as an answer and I
ll accept it.